# How to pass all selected files names to C# application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-xp

I would like to select several files on my desktop (or any other folder) and pass their names to my application.

More specifically, I've added a key to the registry such that when I right click on a jpeg file I see a new "Transform" option that actually runs my application.
The question is how can I pass all selected files names to my application ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'll try to remember that :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They should be passed by windows. Look at the command line arguments passed to your application at start up. ie. in your Main function that has a parameter of string[] args.

To illustrate:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Program called without arguments");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Program received this arguments:");
        foreach (string arg in args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", arg);
        }
    }

    // .. do other stuff
}
```

Comment: However, Windows will start a separate process for every selected file.

Comment: So you say that the selected files will be passed to my application automatically by Windows ?
Another problem that the Main() method that was created automatically does not have the "args" parameter: static void Main() {...}. It was created by Visual Studio when I started a new Windows Forms Application project.

Comment: @divo Great comment.  So I believe he will need something that prevent multiple instances of his app from running, correct?

Comment: Yes, if *all* selected files should be passed to the same instance two things would be needed: A single-instance mechanism, and a mechanism to pass arguments from a newly started instance to the already running instance (e.g. as described here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/SingletonApp.aspx). Or, much simpler, use drag'n'drop to pass all file names at once.

Comment: Guys, can you tell me why the Main() function does not have the "args" parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

If this is something that you want to do while your app is already running, like for example via a drag/drop type operation then there are a few API calls that allow you to perform drag and drop type operations with Shell objects.

Lookup/google IDragSourceHelper, IDropTargetHelper, IDataObject etc.